# Typeahead/Bloodhound Remote not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I am trying to get typeahead (v0.10.5)/bloodhound to bind the returned JSON data.  Unfortunately, nothing appears in my suggestion window (ie, `<input >`).  In addition, I am using jQuery v2.0.3.

The call to my endpoint is successful.  When I inspect the results in Chrome, I see a properly formatted Response (ie, data and Content-type).  There are no errors appearing in the Chrome's console window.  There is an example of the JSON below.

I have inserted **debugger;** statements in the code but they are not getting hit.

The jqXHR.setRequestHeader() is there because I was making some cross site calls.

**Html code**

```
<div id="remote">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Prescription names">
</div>
```

**Javascript code**

*I left the **// debugger**; statements to show where I was trying to add breakpoints.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var prescriptions = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value); },
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

            remote: {
                url: '/Prescription/GetPrescriptions/?searchTerm=%QUERY',
                filter: function (prescriptions) {
                    //debugger;
                    return $.map(prescriptions, function (user) {
                        //debugger;
                        return {
                            value: user.Name 
                        };
                    });
                },
                ajax: {
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                        var authHeaders;
                        // pull apart jqXHR, set authHeaders to what it should be
                        //debugger;
                        jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
        prescriptions.initialize();
        // instantiate the typeahead UI
        $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead({
            minLength: 3,
            highlight: true,
            hint: true
        },
            {
                name: 'prescriptions',
                displayKey: 'value',
                source: prescriptions.ttAdapter()
            });
    });

</script>
```

**JSON Result**

```
[{"Name":"Drug1"}]
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Steve

Comment: So when you enter a search term you see a "GET" request to your "GetPerscriptions" methods as you type?

Comment: I see the GET operation (via Chrome Inspect).  As my example above shows, I get a valid JSON response back.  It just as though the result goes into the 'ether'.  When I enable my debugger; statements, they never get it.

Comment: How odd. As a test try using a full URL instead of a relative one and re-enable the debugger statements.

Comment: #BenSmith, I was able to get it to work.  I changed the dataType: to json.  Removed the jsonp and it worked.

Comment: Great that you got it to work. however as you are using a relative URL it should not be in a different domain? (you use JSONP when accessing data from a different domain).

Comment: #BenSmith, in the end, I am using a relative URL.  In my various iterations, I think I was trying to access an external domain which is why I used the JSONP datatype to resolve a cross-domain issue.

Comment: Ok. I suggest you post your own answer to help other SO users.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had with my code turned out to be the `dataType: "jsonp"` statement.  I went through a number of iterations of my code.  At one point, I was referencing an different domain.  Which led me to use the jsonp datatype.

In the end, I am referencing a Relative Url which did not need to have the jsonp datatype.

I changed the ajax call to `dataType: "json"` and it was fixed.